# transfering the the selected listview item to the clipboard via C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, imagelist

I'm trying to populate images from a directory into a **listview** with a small thumbnail preview using an **imagelist control**. Once the user has selected an Item from the listview I want the selected item to be copied to the clipboard.

I already have the code written to populate the listview. It's a **C# winforms application**.

I'm thinking to try something like this:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
}
```

I'm just having issues getting the data copied to the clipboard.

My question: **how can I transfer the the selected listview item to the clipboard via C#**

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want filename to be copied? Or thumbnail? Or file in directory? What do you want exactly to be copied into the clipboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use (for text)

```
Clipboard.SetText(this.listView1.SelectedItem.Text);
```

or

```
Image imgToCopy = Image.FromFile(this.listView1.SelectedItem.Text);
Clipboard.SetImage(imgToCopy);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement:

```
Clipboard.SetImage(Image);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(object);
Clipboard.SetText(string);
...
```